# Why does the jquery UI doesn't work for the checkbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

Here is [the demo link : http://cistrome.org/cps/sequences?did=2653&Gene_box=&region_select=proximal&distance_nearest_bp_number=5000&distance_further_bp_number=0&displaygenes=genesymbol&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150](http://cistrome.org/cps/sequences?did=2653&Gene_box=&region_select=proximal&distance_nearest_bp_number=5000&distance_further_bp_number=0&displaygenes=genesymbol&extend_bp_number=200&repeat_bp_number=150):

When you first enter the page, the checkbox looks like this:
[image: broken]
The style is broken and it's not clickable.

Only when you **refresh the page**, the checkbox looks normal like this:
[image: good]
It's clickable now.

This is reproducible on Firefox15.0.1.  (**If it works for you in the first time, you can click the blue button `Find binding sites`. And then you may see the broken checkbox..**)

I'm just wondering that why it's broken when you get in the page for the first time, but restores normal when the page is refreshed.
I use firebugs to debug the javascript code but it only says:

```
TypeError: $("#radio_tss").buttonset is not a function
[Break On This Error]   

$("#radio_tss").buttonset();
```

Which makes me confused..

The jquery UI reference of checkbox can be seen here:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio

Does anyone have ideas about what happens to this checkbox?

Thanks!

Comment: Working fine for me the first time in chrome 21, which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using Firefox 15.0.1

Comment: Firefox 15.0.1 works for me... are you sure it's not a cache problem on your side?

Comment: @ZathrusWriter I don't think so.. It's also broken in my Safari browser.. Can you try to click the `find binding sites` button of the page?

Comment: that button submits a form and refreshes page, buttons still work - but I tend to agree with Alnitak - try moving all required JS filed above the code that initializes mygene

Comment: @ZathrusWriter the problem he has is that it's the `mygene` code that's actually loading jQuery and jQuery UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your insertion of dynamic `<script>` tags in the `mygene` module to load jQuery UI will default to `async` execution, sometimes allowing your call to `.buttonset()` to proceed before jQuery UI has actually completed loading.

On the second load the file is already in the browser cache, making the problem less likely.

Comment: I think your answer is right because this problem doesn't exist before adding `mygene` module. Could you give me some suggestion for solving this problem?

Comment: @Firegun ideally you would register `load` handlers for the dynamic script elements and ensure that those have fired before proceeding with the rest of the code.  Deferred objects may help there.

Comment: Do you mean that I move the `mygene` module into `$(function() {...})`? I tried that, but after I do that, `mygene`'s function (auto-completion) won't work well..

Comment: I _think_ it'll just work if you export `mygene_init` and then just call that in your `$(function() { ... })`.